Showing $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin t^2 dt$ converges with previous results
In an exam some months ago, we were supposed to show that if $f$ is a function of class $\mathscr{C}^2$ and bounded on the interval $[0,+\infty)$ satisfying $f'\left(0\right) = 0$ then the following integral converges:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f'\left(t\right)}{t}\text{d}t 
$$
Now I'm asked to use this result to show that integrals $I$ and $J$ converge where:
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t}\text{d}t,$$ and $$J = \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin t^2\text{d}t
$$
By simply choosing $f\left(t\right) = -\cos t$, then $f$ satisfies all the aformentioned properties and we have $I$ exists. So far so good. However, I don't know how to show that $J$ exists following this path. Naturally, I wanted to use
$$
f\left(t\right) = \int_{0}^{t} u \sin u^2\text{d}u
$$
so that $f'\left(t\right) / t = \sin t^2$, while having $f'(0) = 0$ and being $\mathscr{C}^2$, however this function is not bounded !
Can someone guide me a little with a hint ?

When you do the substitution $t^2 = s$ in your integral, you should arrive at an improper integral of the form $\int_0^\infty f'(s)/\sqrt(s) \ ds$. So try to prove the result from your exam question for improper integrals of this form.

Why $\displaystyle\int^t_0u\sin u^2du$ is unbounded? It is exactly equal to $\dfrac{1-\cos t^2}{2}$. More likely pick $f=-\cos t^2/2$.

@AngaeMT Yes, you are fully write, it is bounded ! I wrongly thought that it couldnt due to $u$ within $[o,t]$, but it canbe computed directly... This makes my question an obvious question lol .... Thanks !

Am I wrong or the initial OP’s theorem also works if the function $f$ is not of class $\mathscr C^2!$ on $[0,\infty)$ but it is of class $\mathscr C^1!$ and there exists $f’’(0);?;$ Moreover, is it correct that $$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f'\left(t\right)}{t}\text{d}t=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t^2}\text{d}t;;?$$

@Angelo It seems we only need the existence of $f''(x)$ near $x=0$

@Angelo we are only using $f''$ to prove that as $x\to 0^+$, there are no problems right? If we use the fact that $\frac{f'(t)}t \sim f''(0)$, maybe we only need the existence at $0$

Yes, we are just using $f’’$ for that reason. So, I think we only need the existence of $f’’(x)$ at $x=0$.

@SineoftheTime, one of the hypotheses is that $f’(0)=0$, hence $\lim\limits_{t\to0^+}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}t=0,.;$ Another hypothesis is that $f$ is bounded on $[0,+\infty)$, therefore $\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}t=0,.;$ Consequently, $\bigg[\frac{f(t)-f(0)}t\bigg]_{!0}^{!+\infty}!!!!!!!!=0;$ and just by applying integration by parts, we get the formula I wrote in a previous comment.

I'm dumb, you choose $f(x)-f(0)$ as an antiderivative of $f'(x)$ @Angelo.

For the second one (you almost get the key point):
$$J=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin t^2\text{d}t
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t\sin t^2}{t}\text{d}t,$$
choose $f'(t)=t\sin(t^2)$, then
$$f(t)=\int_{0}^{t}u\sin(u^2)\text{d}u+f(0)
=\frac12\int_{0}^{t^2}\sin(s)\text{d}s+f(0)
=\frac{1}{2}[1-\cos(t^2)]+f(0).$$
$$|f(t)|\leq1+|f(0)|,\quad t\in[0,\infty).$$
This will works: $f$ is bounded on $[0,\infty)$ and $f\in\mathscr{C}^2,f'(0)=0$.
Use the result in the beginning, you will get that $J$ is convergent.
